# stringi package won't install in CentOS

Tags: r, stringi

I am trying to install `stringi` package in `R`, but the installation never finishes. After the download and some compilation, I get the following message:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/marcus/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpT5KQVP/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("stringi") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

I searched the internet and I couldn't understand what this error message means. If it helps, this is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem installing `gcc 4.9.2`. To do so, I ran

```
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-gfortran
$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

in the shell. The first two commands install `gcc` and `gfortran`. The last one makes `gcc 4.9.2` the standard compiler in the system. After that, I opened `R` and ran `install.packages("stringi")` to have my problem solved.